# Alpine JS dynamic style attribute on rollover

Tags: css, alpine.js

I have 2 colour pickers (one for the background and one for the text colour).

They are linked to the styles of a button

```
<button :style="`background-color: ${bg_colour}; color: ${text_colour};`">TEST BUTTON</button>
```

This works fine.

I would like to swap these variables when the button is hovered over or is active. i.e. the background colour becomes the text colour and the text colour becomes the background colour.

Any suggestions? Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `@mouseover` and `@mouseleave` events to swap the colors of the button, furthermore we use the [object-binding syntax](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#binding-styles) as well. In the `x-init` directive, we create two `$watch` listener objects that will update the `styles` object when the user picks a new color.

```html
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{bg_color: '#e66465', text_color: '#000', 
              styles: {'background-color': '#e66465', 'color': '#000'}}"
     x-init="$watch('bg_color', val => styles['background-color'] = val),
             $watch('text_color', val => styles['color'] = val)">
     
<div>
  <input type="color" x-model="bg_color" id="text">
  <label for="text">Background color</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="color" x-model="text_color" id="bg">
  <label for="bg">Text color</label>
</div>

<br>
<div>
  <button @mouseover="styles['color'] = bg_color, styles['background-color'] = text_color"
          @mouseleave="styles['color'] = text_color, styles['background-color'] = bg_color"
          :style="styles">
    Hover to swap colours
  </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Spectacular! Thanks @Dauros